# What is the correct way to draw a TreeViewNode whose content is not a string?

Tags: uwp

I am using a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TreeView` and would like to custom draw the TreeViewNode objects. In particular I would like to store my own objects in the Content property of a TreeViewNode then do some custom drawing of data in the Content object. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: I would be happy to accept your answer but the accept checkmark seems to be missing here.

Comment: I cannot see the accept button.

Comment: Hmmm... I still do not see the accept button.

Comment: There is no checkmark beneath the vote buttons.

Answer (score 0):

> TreeViewNode then do some custom drawing of data in the Content object. What is the correct way to do this?

Please refer this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view), and if you want to custom `TreeViewNode` you could make `ItemTemplateSelector` and edit `TreeViewItem` content in the `DataTemplate`

For example, if you want add image and textblock in to `TreeViewNode` and specific sub-node

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/folder.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" x:DataType="local:ExplorerItem">
        <muxc:TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/file.png"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </muxc:TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ExplorerItemTemplateSelector
            x:Key="ExplorerItemTemplateSelector"
            FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}"
            FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <muxc:TreeView
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind DataSource}"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ExplorerItemTemplateSelector}"/>
</Grid>
```